# A faster way to use Emmet with HAML

Tags: html, haml, sublimetext, emmet

I've just started using HAML in Sublime with Emmet installed. My only gripe is to autocomplete my tags I would have to do something like this for it to convert: `p|haml` when alternatively I could type `%p`, thus defeating the purpose of speed. While some may not see this as an issue I'd much rather follow the same convention of Emmet's standard html functionality where all I'd have to do is type the letter of the HTML tag and hit tab vs. `shift + % + tag`. [Codepen](http://codepein.io/pen) accomplishes this exactly where all I have to do is enable HAML and it takes care of the rest. Is there an existing method or snippet that I can use that mirrors this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

At CodePen we didn't custom code anything to make it work, we use CodeMirror and Emmet for CodeMirror

https://github.com/emmetio/codemirror

Maybe you can dig through there and find what makes it work =)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that in order to use the snippet mentioned in my question that you must explicitly be in a `.haml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Emmet applies `haml` filter for HAML syntax, but it may fail to do so in some editors. For example, when you forget to set current document syntax to HAML or (according to your `sublimetext` tag) you’re using some custom HALM syntax that Emmet can’t recognize.